# Find common tangent line between two cubic curves

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sympy, equation-solving

Given two functions, I would like to sort out the common tangent for both curves:

[image]

The slope of the common tangent can be obtained by the following:

```
slope of common tangent = (f(x1) - g(x2)) / (x1 - x2) = f'(x1) = g'(x2)
```

So that in the end we have a system of 2 equations with 2 unknowns:

```
f'(x1) = g'(x2) # Eq. 1
(f(x1) - g(x2)) / (x1 - x2) = f'(x1) # Eq. 2
```

For some reason I do not understand, python does not find the solution:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys
from sympy import *
import sympy as sym


# Intial candidates for fit 
E0_init = -941.510817926696
V0_init = 63.54960592453
B0_init = 76.3746233515232
B0_prime_init = 4.05340727164527

# Data 1 (Red triangles): 
V_C_I, E_C_I = np.loadtxt('./1.dat', skiprows = 1).T

# Data 14 (Empty grey triangles):
V_14, E_14 = np.loadtxt('./2.dat', skiprows = 1).T

def BM(x, a, b, c, d):
        return  (2.293710449E+17)*(1E-21)* (a + b*x + c*x**2 + d*x**3 )

def P(x, b, c, d):
    return -b - 2*c*x - 3 *d*x**2

init_vals = [E0_init, V0_init, B0_init, B0_prime_init]
popt_C_I, pcov_C_I = curve_fit(BM, V_C_I, E_C_I, p0=init_vals)
popt_14, pcov_14 = curve_fit(BM, V_14, E_14, p0=init_vals)

x1 = var('x1')
x2 = var('x2')

E1 = P(x1, popt_C_I[1], popt_C_I[2], popt_C_I[3]) - P(x2, popt_14[1], popt_14[2], popt_14[3])
print 'E1 = ', E1

E2 = ((BM(x1, popt_C_I[0], popt_C_I[1], popt_C_I[2], popt_C_I[3]) - BM(x2, popt_14[0], popt_14[1], popt_14[2], popt_14[3])) / (x1 - x2)) - P(x1, popt_C_I[1], popt_C_I[2], popt_C_I[3])

sols = solve([E1, E2], [x1, x2])

print 'sols = ', sols

# Linspace for plotting the fitting curves:
V_C_I_lin = np.linspace(V_C_I[0], V_C_I[-1], 10000)
V_14_lin = np.linspace(V_14[0], V_14[-1], 10000)

plt.figure()
# Plotting the fitting curves:
p2, = plt.plot(V_C_I_lin, BM(V_C_I_lin, *popt_C_I), color='black', label='Cubic fit data 1' )
p6, = plt.plot(V_14_lin, BM(V_14_lin, *popt_14), 'b', label='Cubic fit data 2')

# Plotting the scattered points: 
p1 = plt.scatter(V_C_I, E_C_I, color='red', marker="^", label='Data 1', s=100)
p5 = plt.scatter(V_14, E_14, color='grey', marker="^", facecolors='none', label='Data 2', s=100)

plt.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)
plt.show()
```

[image]

`1.dat` is the following:

```
61.6634100000000 -941.2375622594436
62.3429030000000 -941.2377748739724
62.9226515000000 -941.2378903605746
63.0043440000000 -941.2378981684135
63.7160150000000 -941.2378864590100
64.4085050000000 -941.2377753645115
65.1046835000000 -941.2375332100225
65.8049585000000 -941.2372030376584
66.5093925000000 -941.2367456992965
67.2180970000000 -941.2361992239395
67.9311515000000 -941.2355493856510
```

`2.dat` is the following:

```
54.6569312500000 -941.2300821583739
55.3555152500000 -941.2312112888004
56.1392347500000 -941.2326135552780
56.9291575000000 -941.2338291772218
57.6992532500000 -941.2348135408652
58.4711572500000 -941.2356230099117
59.2666985000000 -941.2362715934311
60.0547935000000 -941.2367074271724
60.8626545000000 -941.2370273047416
```

**Update:** Using @if.... approach:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties

# Intial candidates for fit, per FU: - thus, the E vs V input data has to be per FU
E0_init = -941.510817926696   
V0_init = 63.54960592453  
B0_init = 76.3746233515232  
B0_prime_init = 4.05340727164527 

def BM(x, a, b, c, d):
         return  a + b*x + c*x**2 + d*x**3 

def devBM(x, b, c, d):
         return  b + 2*c*x + 3*d*x**2 

# Data 1 (Red triangles): 
V_C_I, E_C_I = np.loadtxt('./1.dat', skiprows = 1).T

# Data 14 (Empty grey triangles):
V_14, E_14 = np.loadtxt('./2.dat', skiprows = 1).T

init_vals = [E0_init, V0_init, B0_init, B0_prime_init]
popt_C_I, pcov_C_I = curve_fit(BM, V_C_I, E_C_I, p0=init_vals)
popt_14, pcov_14 = curve_fit(BM, V_14, E_14, p0=init_vals)

from scipy.optimize import fsolve
def equations(p):
    x1, x2 = p
    E1 = devBM(x1, popt_C_I[1], popt_C_I[2], popt_C_I[3]) - devBM(x2, popt_14[1], popt_14[2], popt_14[3])
    E2 = ((BM(x1, popt_C_I[0], popt_C_I[1], popt_C_I[2], popt_C_I[3]) - BM(x2, popt_14[0], popt_14[1], popt_14[2], popt_14[3])) / (x1 - x2)) - devBM(x1, popt_C_I[1], popt_C_I[2], popt_C_I[3])
    return (E1, E2)

x1, x2 =  fsolve(equations, (50, 60))
print 'x1 = ', x1
print 'x2 = ', x2

slope_common_tangent = devBM(x1, popt_C_I[1], popt_C_I[2], popt_C_I[3])
print 'slope_common_tangent = ', slope_common_tangent

def comm_tangent(x, x1, slope_common_tangent):
   return BM(x1, popt_C_I[0], popt_C_I[1], popt_C_I[2], popt_C_I[3]) - slope_common_tangent * x1 + slope_common_tangent * x

# Linspace for plotting the fitting curves:
V_C_I_lin = np.linspace(V_C_I[0], V_C_I[-1], 10000)
V_14_lin = np.linspace(V_14[0], V_14[-1], 10000)

plt.figure()

# Plotting the fitting curves:
p2, = plt.plot(V_C_I_lin, BM(V_C_I_lin, *popt_C_I), color='black', label='Cubic fit Calcite I' )
p6, = plt.plot(V_14_lin, BM(V_14_lin, *popt_14), 'b', label='Cubic fit Calcite II')

xp = np.linspace(54, 68, 100)
pcomm_tangent, = plt.plot(xp, comm_tangent(xp, x1, slope_common_tangent), 'green', label='Common tangent')

# Plotting the scattered points: 
p1 = plt.scatter(V_C_I, E_C_I, color='red', marker="^", label='Calcite I', s=100)
p5 = plt.scatter(V_14, E_14, color='grey', marker="^", facecolors='none', label='Calcite II', s=100)

fontP = FontProperties()
fontP.set_size('13')

plt.legend((p1, p2, p5, p6, pcomm_tangent), ("1", "Cubic fit 1", "2", 'Cubic fit 2', 'Common tangent'), prop=fontP)

print 'devBM(x1, popt_C_I[1], popt_C_I[2], popt_C_I[3]) = ', devBM(x1, popt_C_I[1], popt_C_I[2], popt_C_I[3])

plt.ylim(-941.240, -941.225) 
plt.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)

plt.show()
```

I am able to find the common tangent, as shown below:

[image]

However, this common tangent corresponds to a common tangent in an area outside the data range, i.e., using

```
V_C_I_lin = np.linspace(V_C_I[0]-30, V_C_I[-1], 10000)
V_14_lin = np.linspace(V_14[0]-20, V_14[-1]+2, 10000)
xp = np.linspace(40, 70, 100)
plt.ylim(-941.25, -941.18)
```

is possible to see the following:

[image]

Is it possible to constraint the solver to the range where we have data in order to find the desired common tangent?

**Update 2.1**: Using @if.... Range constraints approach, the following code yields `x1 = 61.2569899` and `x2 = 59.7677843`. If we plot it:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties
import sys
from sympy import *
import sympy as sym
import os

# Intial candidates for fit, per FU: - thus, the E vs V input data has to be per FU
E0_init = -941.510817926696  # -1882.50963222/2.0 
V0_init = 63.54960592453 #125.8532/2.0 
B0_init = 76.3746233515232 #74.49 
B0_prime_init = 4.05340727164527 #4.15

def BM(x, a, b, c, d):
         return  a + b*x + c*x**2 + d*x**3

def devBM(x, b, c, d):
         return  b + 2*c*x + 3*d*x**2

# Data 1 (Red triangles): 
V_C_I, E_C_I = np.loadtxt('./1.dat', skiprows = 1).T

# Data 14 (Empty grey triangles):
V_14, E_14 = np.loadtxt('./2.dat', skiprows = 1).T

init_vals = [E0_init, V0_init, B0_init, B0_prime_init]
popt_C_I, pcov_C_I = curve_fit(BM, V_C_I, E_C_I, p0=init_vals)
popt_14, pcov_14 = curve_fit(BM, V_14, E_14, p0=init_vals)

def equations(p):
    x1, x2 = p
    E1 = devBM(x1, popt_C_I[1], popt_C_I[2], popt_C_I[3]) - devBM(x2, popt_14[1], popt_14[2], popt_14[3])
    E2 = ((BM(x1, popt_C_I[0], popt_C_I[1], popt_C_I[2], popt_C_I[3]) - BM(x2, popt_14[0], popt_14[1], popt_14[2], popt_14[3])) / (x1 - x2)) - devBM(x1, popt_C_I[1], popt_C_I[2], popt_C_I[3])
    return (E1, E2)

from scipy.optimize import least_squares
lb = (61.0, 59.0)   # lower bounds on x1, x2
ub = (62.0, 60.0)    # upper bounds
result = least_squares(equations, [61, 59], bounds=(lb, ub))
print 'result = ', result

# The result obtained is:
# x1 = 61.2569899
# x2 = 59.7677843

slope_common_tangent = devBM(x1, popt_C_I[1], popt_C_I[2], popt_C_I[3])
print 'slope_common_tangent = ', slope_common_tangent


def comm_tangent(x, x1, slope_common_tangent):
   return BM(x1, popt_C_I[0], popt_C_I[1], popt_C_I[2], popt_C_I[3]) - slope_common_tangent * x1 + slope_common_tangent * x

# Linspace for plotting the fitting curves:
V_C_I_lin = np.linspace(V_C_I[0]-2, V_C_I[-1], 10000)
V_14_lin = np.linspace(V_14[0], V_14[-1]+2, 10000)


fig_handle = plt.figure()

# Plotting the fitting curves:
p2, = plt.plot(V_C_I_lin, BM(V_C_I_lin, *popt_C_I), color='black' )
p6, = plt.plot(V_14_lin, BM(V_14_lin, *popt_14), 'b' )

xp = np.linspace(54, 68, 100)
pcomm_tangent, = plt.plot(xp, comm_tangent(xp, x1, slope_common_tangent), 'green', label='Common tangent')

# Plotting the scattered points: 
p1 = plt.scatter(V_C_I, E_C_I, color='red', marker="^", label='1', s=100)
p5 = plt.scatter(V_14, E_14, color='grey', marker="^", facecolors='none', label='2', s=100)

fontP = FontProperties()
fontP.set_size('13')

plt.legend((p1, p2, p5, p6, pcomm_tangent), ("1", "Cubic fit 1", "2", 'Cubic fit 2', 'Common tangent'), prop=fontP)


plt.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)

plt.show()
```

We see that we are not obtaining a common tangent:

[image]

Comment: a Minimal example would just start with the cubic parameters, we don't need the fitting process if your problem is where you believe

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Symbolic root finding

Your system of equations consists of a quadratic equation and a cubic equation. There is no closed-form symbolic solution of such a system. Indeed, if there was, one would be able to apply it to a general 5th degree equation `x**5 + a*x**4 + ... = 0` by introducing `y = x**2` (quadratic) and rewriting the original equation as `x*y**2 + a*y**2 + ... = 0` (cubic). And we know that [can't be done](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintic_function). So it's not surprising that SymPy can't solve it. You need a numeric solver (another reason is that SymPy isn't really designed to solve equations full of floating point constants, they are trouble for symbolic manipulations).

#### Numeric root finding

[SciPy fsolve](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html) is the first thing that comes to mind. You could do something like this:

```
def F(x):
    x1, x2 = x[0], x[1]
    E1 = P(x1, popt_C_I[1], popt_C_I[2], popt_C_I[3]) - P(x2, popt_14[1], popt_14[2], popt_14[3])
    E2 = ((BM(x1, popt_C_I[0], popt_C_I[1], popt_C_I[2], popt_C_I[3]) - BM(x2, popt_14[0], popt_14[1], popt_14[2], popt_14[3])) / (x1 - x2)) - P(x1, popt_C_I[1], popt_C_I[2], popt_C_I[3])
    return [E1, E2] 

print fsolve(F, [50, 60])    # some reasonable initial point
```

By the way, I would move (x1-x2) from the denominator in E2, rewriting E2 as

```
(...) - (x1 - x2) * P(x1, popt_C_I[1], popt_C_I[2], popt_C_I[3])
```

so the system is polynomial. This will likely make the life of `fsolve` a little easier.

#### Range constraints: minimization

Neither `fsolve` nor its relatives like `root` support placing bounds on the variables. But you can use `least_squares` which will look for the minimum of the sum of squares of expressions E1, E2. It supports upper and lower bounds, and with any luck, the minimum value ("cost") will be 0 within machine precision, indicating you found a root. An abstract example (since I don't have your data):

```
f1 = lambda x: 2*x**3 + 20
df1 = lambda x: 6*x**2   # derivative of f1. 
f2 = lambda x: (x-3)**3 + x
df2 = lambda x: 3*(x-3)**2 + 1

def eqns(x):
    x1, x2 = x[0], x[1]
    eq1 = df1(x1) - df2(x2)
    eq2 = df1(x1)*(x1 - x2) - (f1(x1) - f2(x2))
    return [eq1, eq2]

from scipy.optimize import least_squares
lb = (2, -2)   # lower bounds on x1, x2
ub = (5, 3)    # upper bounds
least_squares(eqns, [3, 1], bounds=(lb, ub))
```

Output:

```
 active_mask: array([0, 0])
        cost: 2.524354896707238e-29
         fun: array([7.10542736e-15, 0.00000000e+00])
        grad: array([1.93525199e-13, 1.34611132e-13])
         jac: array([[27.23625045, 18.94483256],
       [66.10672633, -0.        ]])
     message: '`gtol` termination condition is satisfied.'
        nfev: 8
        njev: 8
  optimality: 2.4802477446153134e-13
      status: 1
     success: True
           x: array([ 2.26968753, -0.15747203])
```

The cost is very small, so we have a solution, and it is x. Typically, one assigns the output of `least_squares` to some variable `res` and accesses `res.x` from there.

Comment: Thanks a lot you for your answer. I have implemented your approach, but this unfortunately does not yield the correct equation. Please see updated post.

Comment: The equations E1 and E2 are based on the assumption that P is the derivative of BM. In your code, P is not the derivative of BM. So you need something that is the derivative of BM.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this comment. I have fixed the code. However, the common tangent found is outside the data range and therefore it is not the desired common tangent equation. Please see updated post. Is there a way to find the desired common tangent within the data range?

Comment: Thank you for your update. As a side note, the data has always been provided in the post, just in case, for the sake of reproducing the same behaviour. I have applied your Range Constraints approach to this case, but is not able of finding the solution. Please see update 2. Many thanks again

Comment: The error message says exactly what the problem is: the initial point is infeasible (meaning: does not satisfy the constraints). You gave a lower bound of 61 on the first coordinate, but the initial value is 60.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have fixed it, please see updated post. However, for some reason I don't understand this is still not the correct common tangent

Comment: It's close. The derivative looks about the same at those two points, and the tangent is pretty close to being tangent at the other place, too. It seems the minimizer decided it's good enough and stopped. You should read its output to see what termination condition is responsible for stopping, and tighten it up by decreasing the corresponding parameter. The default stopping parameters are ftol=1e-08, xtol=1e-08, gtol=1e-08; see [SciPy docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html#scipy.optimize.least_squares)

Comment: Reading full output of least_squares is also useful because it contains the __cost__, which is the thing that should be very close to 0. If it isn't, you know the solution isn't going to be very good even without plotting it.

Comment: @ if.... Thank you very much for both comments. Please see my below answer: I have studied tighter tolerances on the `least_squares`. The cost is even lower for tighter tolerances (something I quite don't understand?). Also I found a way for `fsolve` to work, just by restricting the `x` space. Please feel free to comment.

Comment: @DavidC. Lower cost is good. It means least_squares got closer to a solution. Ideally the cost would be 0. Tolerance values tell the optimization process when it can stop. Smaller tolerance make it work longer, so it's more likely to find something good.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to all @if.... help, by running the below code posted at the end of this answer, the result of 3 pathways are discussed:

## **1)** `least_squares` with default tolerances:

```
####  ftol=1e-08, xtol=1e-08, gtol=1e-08  #####

result =   active_mask: array([0, 0])
        cost: 4.7190963603923405e-10
         fun: array([  1.60076424e-05,   2.62216448e-05])
        grad: array([ -3.22762954e-09,  -4.72137063e-09])
         jac: array([[  2.70753295e-04,  -3.41257603e-04],
       [ -2.88378229e-04,   2.82727898e-05]])
     message: '`gtol` termination condition is satisfied.'
        nfev: 4
        njev: 4
  optimality: 2.398161337354571e-09
      status: 1
     success: True
           x: array([ 61.2569899,  59.7677843])
result.x =  [ 61.2569899  59.7677843]



slope_common_tangent =  -0.000533908881355
```

Cost is zero, and the common tangent found is very close, but not ideal:

[image]

## **2)** `least_squares` with tighter tolerances:

```
####  ftol=1e-12, xtol=1e-12, gtol=1e-12  #####

result_tight_tols =   active_mask: array([0, 0])
        cost: 4.3861335617475759e-20
         fun: array([  2.08437035e-10,   2.10420231e-10])
        grad: array([ -5.40980234e-16,  -7.19344843e-14])
         jac: array([[  2.69431398e-04,  -3.45167744e-04],
       [ -2.69462978e-04,   5.34965061e-08]])
     message: '`gtol` termination condition is satisfied.'
        nfev: 8
        njev: 8
  optimality: 7.6628451334260651e-15
      status: 1
     success: True
           x: array([ 61.35744106,  59.89347466])
result_tight_tols.x =  [ 61.35744106  59.89347466]



slope_common_tangent =  -0.000506777791299
```

I was expecting the cost to be higher, but for some reason I do not understand, the cost is even lower. The common tangent found is much more closer:

[image]

## **3)** Using `fsolve` but restricting the region

We saw in the post that when using `x1, x2 =  fsolve(equations, (50, 60))`, the common tangent found was not the correct one (2nd and 3rd images). However, if we use `x1, x2 =  fsolve(equations, (61.5, 62))`:

```
#### Using `fsolve`, but restricting the region:  ####


x1 =  61.3574418449
x2 =  59.8934758773
slope_common_tangent =  -0.000506777580856
```

We see that the slope found is very similar to the `least_squares` with tighter tolerances. Thus, the common tangent found is also very close:

[image]

This table summarises the results:

[image]

Code that produces these three pathways:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties
import sys
from sympy import *
import sympy as sym
import os
import pickle as pl


# Intial candidates for fit, per FU: - thus, the E vs V input data has to be per FU
E0_init = -941.510817926696  # -1882.50963222/2.0 
V0_init = 63.54960592453 #125.8532/2.0 
B0_init = 76.3746233515232 #74.49 
B0_prime_init = 4.05340727164527 #4.15

def BM(x, a, b, c, d):
         return  a + b*x + c*x**2 + d*x**3 

def devBM(x, b, c, d):
         return  b + 2*c*x + 3*d*x**2 

# Data 1 (Red triangles): 
V_C_I, E_C_I = np.loadtxt('./1.dat', skiprows = 1).T

# Data 14 (Empty grey triangles):
V_14, E_14 = np.loadtxt('./2.dat', skiprows = 1).T

init_vals = [E0_init, V0_init, B0_init, B0_prime_init]
popt_C_I, pcov_C_I = curve_fit(BM, V_C_I, E_C_I, p0=init_vals)
popt_14, pcov_14 = curve_fit(BM, V_14, E_14, p0=init_vals)


def equations(p):
    x1, x2 = p
    E1 = devBM(x1, popt_C_I[1], popt_C_I[2], popt_C_I[3]) - devBM(x2, popt_14[1], popt_14[2], popt_14[3])
    E2 = ((BM(x1, popt_C_I[0], popt_C_I[1], popt_C_I[2], popt_C_I[3]) - BM(x2, popt_14[0], popt_14[1], popt_14[2], popt_14[3])) / (x1 - x2)) - devBM(x1, popt_C_I[1], popt_C_I[2], popt_C_I[3])
    return (E1, E2)

from scipy.optimize import least_squares
lb = (61.0, 59.0)   # lower bounds on x1, x2
ub = (62.0, 60.0)   # upper bounds
result = least_squares(equations, [61, 59], bounds=(lb, ub))
result_tight_tols = least_squares(equations, [61, 59], ftol=1e-12, xtol=1e-12, gtol=1e-12, bounds=(lb, ub))

print """
####  ftol=1e-08, xtol=1e-08, gtol=1e-08  #####
"""
print 'result = ', result
print 'result.x = ', result.x
print """

"""
x1 = result.x[0]
x2 = result.x[1]

slope_common_tangent = devBM(x1, popt_C_I[1], popt_C_I[2], popt_C_I[3])
print 'slope_common_tangent = ', slope_common_tangent

def comm_tangent(x, x1, slope_common_tangent):
   return BM(x1, popt_C_I[0], popt_C_I[1], popt_C_I[2], popt_C_I[3]) - slope_common_tangent * x1 + slope_common_tangent * x

# Linspace for plotting the fitting curves:
V_C_I_lin = np.linspace(V_C_I[0]-2, V_C_I[-1], 10000)
V_14_lin = np.linspace(V_14[0], V_14[-1]+2, 10000)


plt.figure()

# Plotting the fitting curves:
p2, = plt.plot(V_C_I_lin, BM(V_C_I_lin, *popt_C_I), color='black' )
p6, = plt.plot(V_14_lin, BM(V_14_lin, *popt_14), 'b' )

xp = np.linspace(54, 68, 100)
pcomm_tangent, = plt.plot(xp, comm_tangent(xp, x1, slope_common_tangent), 'green', label='Common tangent')

# Plotting the scattered points: 
p1 = plt.scatter(V_C_I, E_C_I, color='red', marker="^", label='1', s=100)
p5 = plt.scatter(V_14, E_14, color='grey', marker="^", facecolors='none', label='2', s=100)

fontP = FontProperties()
fontP.set_size('13')

plt.legend((p1, p2, p5, p6, pcomm_tangent), ("1", "Cubic fit 1", "2", 'Cubic fit 2', 'Common tangent'), prop=fontP)
plt.title('Least squares. Default tolerances: ftol=1e-08, xtol=1e-08, gtol=1e-08')

plt.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)

### Tighter tolerances:
print """
####  ftol=1e-12, xtol=1e-12, gtol=1e-12  #####
"""
print 'result_tight_tols = ', result_tight_tols
print 'result_tight_tols.x = ', result_tight_tols.x
print """

"""
x1 = result_tight_tols.x[0]
x2 = result_tight_tols.x[1]

slope_common_tangent = devBM(x1, popt_C_I[1], popt_C_I[2], popt_C_I[3])
print 'slope_common_tangent = ', slope_common_tangent

def comm_tangent(x, x1, slope_common_tangent):
   return BM(x1, popt_C_I[0], popt_C_I[1], popt_C_I[2], popt_C_I[3]) - slope_common_tangent * x1 + slope_common_tangent * x

# Linspace for plotting the fitting curves:
V_C_I_lin = np.linspace(V_C_I[0]-2, V_C_I[-1], 10000)
V_14_lin = np.linspace(V_14[0], V_14[-1]+2, 10000)


plt.figure()

# Plotting the fitting curves:
p2, = plt.plot(V_C_I_lin, BM(V_C_I_lin, *popt_C_I), color='black' )
p6, = plt.plot(V_14_lin, BM(V_14_lin, *popt_14), 'b' )

xp = np.linspace(54, 68, 100)
pcomm_tangent, = plt.plot(xp, comm_tangent(xp, x1, slope_common_tangent), 'green', label='Common tangent')

# Plotting the scattered points: 
p1 = plt.scatter(V_C_I, E_C_I, color='red', marker="^", label='1', s=100)
p5 = plt.scatter(V_14, E_14, color='grey', marker="^", facecolors='none', label='2', s=100)

fontP = FontProperties()
fontP.set_size('13')

plt.legend((p1, p2, p5, p6, pcomm_tangent), ("1", "Cubic fit 1", "2", 'Cubic fit 2', 'Common tangent'), prop=fontP)
plt.title('ftol=1e-08, xtol=1e-08, gtol=1e-08')

plt.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)

plt.title('Lest Squares. Tightening tolerances: ftol=1e-12, xtol=1e-12, gtol=1e-12')

print """
#### Using `fsolve`, but restricting the region:  ####

"""

from scipy.optimize import fsolve
x1, x2 =  fsolve(equations, (61.5, 62))

print 'x1 = ', x1
print 'x2 = ', x2

slope_common_tangent = devBM(x1, popt_C_I[1], popt_C_I[2], popt_C_I[3])
print 'slope_common_tangent = ', slope_common_tangent

plt.figure()

# Plotting the fitting curves:
p2, = plt.plot(V_C_I_lin, BM(V_C_I_lin, *popt_C_I), color='black' )
p6, = plt.plot(V_14_lin, BM(V_14_lin, *popt_14), 'b' )

xp = np.linspace(54, 68, 100)
pcomm_tangent, = plt.plot(xp, comm_tangent(xp, x1, slope_common_tangent), 'green', label='Common tangent')

# Plotting the scattered points: 
p1 = plt.scatter(V_C_I, E_C_I, color='red', marker="^", label='1', s=100)
p5 = plt.scatter(V_14, E_14, color='grey', marker="^", facecolors='none', label='2', s=100)

fontP = FontProperties()
fontP.set_size('13')

plt.legend((p1, p2, p5, p6, pcomm_tangent), ("1", "Cubic fit 1", "2", 'Cubic fit 2', 'Common tangent'), prop=fontP)
plt.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)

plt.title('Using `fsolve`, but restricting the region')



plt.show()
```

Comment: You didn't restrict the region in `fsolve`, there is no such option there. The tuple you provided, `(61.5, 62)`, is used as the starting point x0 (see [fsolve docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html)). If a starting point is closer to the solution you want, `fsolve` is more likely to find it, instead of going off somewhere and eventually converging to another, undesired, solution.